# Can I use Liquid Haskell on code that requires GHC 8?

Tags: haskell, ghc, liquid-haskell

I have a project that is build with stack and requires GHC 8. Is it possible to use Liquid Haskell with my project, given that it requires GHC 8? If so, how should I go about installing and executing Liquid Haskell?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends... the liquid haskell page says "A modest subset of the language is currently supported *(monads recently included!…)*", which tells me that anything that uses any new features (e.g. polykinds) is almost certainly not going to be supported.  But I it sounds like you are expecting LH to verify your dependencies, and I don't really think it's built for that. It's possible your own code could still be supported, depending on which features you use.  Anyway... sounds like you haven't even installed it yet?  Maybe start by toying around with it.

Answer (score 1):

yes! You can -- LH supports GHC 8.0.2 now (not 8.2 yet...) You can build/run following the instructions here:

https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/blob/develop/INSTALL.md#build-with-stack-recommended

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)